# Joomla site: How to track down source of a google font url?

Tags: joomla, google-font-api

I've gone through all the template .php, .css, .xml files but I can't find the link to a google font that I don't need and want to stop from calling.

I'm sure it must be buried in the many, many files that Joomla combines to build the webpage.

Site is Joomla, latest version. Template is Favourite. Font I want to kill from loading is Google "Lato"

https://rcidaky.com

Comment: Did you check the template styles to see if is selected there?  Are you using Chrome developer tools or similar to look at your rendered code?

Comment: Yes, the template settings are all clear of Google fonts. Thanks

Comment: Did you buy this template? Also you will be better off at [joomla.se]

Answer (score 0):

The fonts that are loaded depend on what is selected in the template settings.

The default font in the template settings is Lato:

[image: Joomla Favourite Template Font Settings]

It doesn't look like there is an option to disable loading a Google font in the template settings.

The code that loads the fonts is located in the template file at `/templates/favourite/index.php` at line 78:

```
<!-- GOOGLE FONT -->
<!-- navigation -->
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=<?php echo str_replace(' ', '+',$this->params->get('nav_google_font'));?>:<?php echo ($this->params->get('nav_google_font_weight')); ?><?php echo str_replace('normal', '',$this->params->get('nav_google_font_style'));?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<!-- titles -->
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=<?php echo str_replace(' ', '+',$this->params->get('titles_google_font'));?>:<?php echo ($this->params->get('titles_google_font_weight')); ?><?php echo str_replace('normal', '',$this->params->get('titles_google_font_style'));?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<!-- text logo -->
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=<?php echo str_replace(' ', '+',$this->params->get('text_logo_google_font'));?>:<?php echo ($this->params->get('text_logo_google_font_weight')); ?><?php echo str_replace('normal', '',$this->params->get('text_logo_google_font_style'));?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<!-- default -->
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I was able to find this code by downloading the template install file, expanding the ZIP file to a local folder and then searching the files for occurrences of "googleapis".

The only two files where this string occurs are the template `index.php` file and the `templateDetails.xml` file.

I'm pretty sure the above code is what you are looking for.

An alternative solution (which doesn't involve editing the code) might be to use a suitable plugin such as [JMG Disable Google Font](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jmg-disable-google-font).

Comment: Yes, I've examined the source code and used Chrome inspector, but Joomla combines many files to build the index.php page on the fly, so I can't find where the link to the Google API is so I can delete it.  Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer to explain where the template `index.php` file resides.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I know how and have edited the template index.php. It is not in that file, it is added dynamically by some other component or plug-in or something that I can't find and that is what I'm trying to track down. (I have added links to the Adobe Typekit file I am using in the index.php file.

Comment: OK, I have added some more detail to the answer and have probably reached my limit on how much I can help with this.

Comment: This template must be non-standard because I've gone through the xml, css, and .php files in the template directory and it's just not there. Thanks for the feedback! I'll just have to live with the extra call for now. It's just a performance issue.

Comment: OK, I have added an alternative solution for you.